# Weird enum in destructor

Tags: c++, enums

Currently, I am reading the source code of `Protocol Buffer`, and I found one weird `enum` codes defined [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/stubs/scoped_ptr.h#L72-L75)

```
  ~scoped_ptr() {
    enum { type_must_be_complete = sizeof(C) };
    delete ptr_;
  }

  void reset(C* p = NULL) {
    if (p != ptr_) {
      enum { type_must_be_complete = sizeof(C) };
      delete ptr_;
      ptr_ = p;
    }
  }
```

Why the `enum { type_must_be_complete = sizeof(C) };` is defined here? what is it used for?

Comment: If I want to be that sure, then I'd rather use `ptr_` itself in the `sizeof` as `sizeof(*ptr_)` instead of `sizeof(C)`.

Answer (score 81):

This trick avoids UB by ensuring that definition  of C is available when this destructor is compiled. Otherwise the compilation would fail as the `sizeof` incomplete type (forward declared types) can not be determined but the pointers can be used.

In compiled binary, this code would be optimized out and would have no effect.

Note that: **Deleting incomplete type may be undefined behavior** from 5.3.5/5:.

> if the object being deleted has **incomplete class** type at the point of
>   deletion and the complete class has a **non-trivial destructor** or a
>   deallocation function, the **behavior is undefined**.

`g++` even issues the following warning:

> warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete
>   operator:
>  warning: 'p' has incomplete type
>  warning: forward
>   declaration of 'struct C'

Comment: "Deleting incomplete type is undefined behavior" is incorrect. It's only UB if the type has a non-trivial destructor. The problem that this little trick addresses is precisely that deleting incomplete type is *not* always UB, so that the language supports it.

Comment: Thanks @Cheersandhth.-Alf My point was it may be UB, so in general this line of code is UB. Edited.

Answer (score 32):

`sizeof(C)` will fail at *compile time* if `C` is not a complete type. Setting a local scope `enum` to it makes the statement benign at runtime.

It's a way of the programmer protecting themselves from themselves: the behaviour of a subsequent `delete ptr_` on an incomplete type is undefined if it has a non-trivial destructor.

Comment: Can you explain why C needs to be a complete type at that point - is it necessary to have the complete type definition to call `delete` on it? And if so, why doesn't the compiler catch it anyway?

Comment: Isn't it rather about avoid `C = void`? If `C` were merely an undefined type, wouldn't the `delete` statement already fail?

Comment: @KerrekSB isn't the point of the check to avoid deleting *incomplete* type - which is UB - rather than an undefined one, which would simply fail?

Comment: Looks like Mohit Jain has got the answer.

Comment: @user2079303: I mean "undefined" as "declared but not defined". Of course the name has to be declared. Anyway, the answer is right: "sizeof(incomplete)" is ill-formed, where as "delete incomplete" may be UB at runtime.

Comment: **−1** "Setting a local scope enum to it makes the statement benign at runtime." is, uh, meaningless. I'm sorry.

Comment: In the context of older compilers (at which this is construct is aimed), I'm not so sure of that. But no need to apologise ;-)

Comment: @PeterHull: type `C` needs to be complete so that the compiler knows what code to emit for `delete ptr_`. It might require a destructor call, and that destructor call may or may not be virtual, only the class definition tells you which. And operator `delete` might be overloaded but that's a slightly separate issue from whether the type is complete. Although the standard doesn't spell it out in so may words, the rules as they are ensure that `delete` of an incomplete type needn't make any destructor call at all, which is correct if the type is trivially destructible but not so much otherwise.

Comment: @SteveJessop thanks. The part I was missing was that deleting an incomplete type is UB.

Answer (score 29):

To understand the `enum`, start with considering the destructor without it:

```
~scoped_ptr() {
    delete ptr_;
}
```

where `ptr_` is a `C*`. If type `C` is incomplete at this point, i.e. all that the compiler knows is `struct C;`, then <sup>(1)</sup>a *default-generated* do-nothing destructor is used for the C instance pointed to. That's unlikely to be the right thing to do for an object managed by a smart pointer.

If deleting via a pointer to incomplete type had always had Undefined Behavior, then the standard could just require the compiler to diagnose it and fail. But it's well-defined when the real destructor is trivial: knowledge that the programmer can have, but the compiler doesn't have. Why the language defines and allows this is beyond me, but C++ supports many practices that today are not regarded as best practices.

A complete type has a known size, and hence, `sizeof(C)` will compile if and only if `C` is a complete type -- with known destructor. So it can be used as a guard. One way would be simply

```
(void) sizeof(C);  // Type must be complete
```

I would *guess* that with some compiler and options the compiler optimizes it away before it could notice that it shouldn't compile, and that the `enum` is a way to avoid such non-conforming compiler behavior:

```
enum { type_must_be_complete = sizeof(C) };
```

An alternative explanation for the choice of `enum` rather than just a discarded expression, is simply personal preference.

Or as James T. Hugget suggests [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800783/weird-enum-in-destructor/33801155?noredirect=1#comment55372517_33801155) to this answer, “The enum may be a way of creating a pseudo-portable error message at compile time”.

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> The default-generated do-nothing destructor for an incomplete type was a problem with old `std::auto_ptr`. It was so insidious that it made its way into [a GOTW item about the PIMPL idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm), written by the chair of the international C++ standardization committee Herb Sutter. Of course, nowadays that `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated, one will instead use some other mechanism.</sup>

Comment: The enum may be a way of creating a pseudo-portable error message at compile time.

Comment: I think this answer explains the motivation of the code very well but I'd like to add that (1) some compilers have `sizeof(T)` evaluate to 0 for incomplete types instead of failing the compile. This is non-conforming behavior, however. (2) Since C++11, using `static_assert((sizeof(T) > 0), "T must be a complete type");` would be a superior (and idiomatic) solution.

Comment: @5gon12eder; Please provide an example of a C++ compiler that has “`sizeof(T)` evaluate to 0 for incomplete types”.

Comment: Re @5gon12eder's claim that `static_assert(sizeof(T) > 0,"...")` is idiomatic, it is not; instead of being widely used, it's meaningless with a conforming compiler.

Comment: I have never used such a compiler and I wouldn't be surprised to hear that they have died out by now. And even if they haven't, not caring about a non-conforming implementation is a valid decision. Nevertheless, both [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/unique_ptr.h?view=co&revision=227595&content-type=text%2Fplain) and [libc++](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/memory) use `static_assert(sizeof(T) > 0, "…");` in their respective implementations of `std::unique_ptr` to make sure the type is complete …

Comment: … so I think it is safe to say this is idiomatic. Anyway, since evaluating `sizeof(T)` in a boolean context is exactly equivalent to testing `sizeof(T) > 0`, it doesn't really matter except maybe for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a trick to be sure `C` is defined.